# Transaction failure reported inspite of succesful data write in db using CallableStatement

Tags: jdbc, websphere

We are getting transaction failure inspite of data being successfully saved in table. The query execution time is very less as compared to the transaction db timeout that has been configured.

This is a scenario of inter application request-response based messaging, both applications individually deployed on WAS server.

```
[9/21/18 12:36:02:432 CEST] 00000021 TimeoutManage I   WTRN0124I: When the timeout occurred the thread with which the transaction is, or was most recently, associated was Thread[Messenger-Listener-95,5,main]. The stack trace of this thread when the timeout occurred was: 
    java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:140)
    oracle.net.ns.Packet.receive(Packet.java:300)
    oracle.net.ns.DataPacket.receive(DataPacket.java:106)
    oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.getNextPacket(NetInputStream.java:315)
    oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:260)
    oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:185)
    oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:102)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.readNextPacket(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:124)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.read(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:80)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1137)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:290)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:192)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.doOall8(T4CCallableStatement.java:204)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.executeForRows(T4CCallableStatement.java:1041)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1329)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3584)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.execute(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3685)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.execute(OracleCallableStatement.java:4714)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.execute(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1376)
    com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcPreparedStatement.execute(WSJdbcPreparedStatement.java:618)
    com.rbc.spp.wfl.WorkflowListener.Insert_CDSC_MF_IMPORT(WorkflowListener.java:98)
    com.rbc.spp.wfl.WorkflowListener.onMessage(WorkflowListener.java:71)
    com.rbc.commons.eden.listener.ESBListener.doBusiness(ESBListener.java:119)
    com.rbc.commons.eden.listener.ESBListener.doBusiness(ESBListener.java:26)
    com.rbc.commons.eden.listener.AbstractListener.onMessage(AbstractListener.java:68)
    com.rbcdexia.eden.internal.messenger.InternalMessenger.processMessage(InternalMessenger.java:972)
    com.rbcdexia.eden.internal.connector.enterprise.Listener.getAndProcess(Listener.java:149)
    com.rbcdexia.eden.internal.connector.AbstractListener.run(AbstractListener.java:83)
    org.springframework.scheduling.commonj.DelegatingWork.run(DelegatingWork.java:61)
    com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.J2EEContext$RunProxy.run(J2EEContext.java:266)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:384)
    javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:495)
    com.ibm.websphere.security.auth.WSSubject.doAs(WSSubject.java:131)
    com.ibm.websphere.security.auth.WSSubject.doAs(WSSubject.java:89)
    com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.J2EEContext$DoAsProxy.run(J2EEContext.java:337)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:413)
    com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.J2EEContext.run(J2EEContext.java:1146)
    com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.WorkWithExecutionContextImpl.go(WorkWithExecutionContextImpl.java:199)
    com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.CJWorkItemImpl.run(CJWorkItemImpl.java:188)
    com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1662)
```

The code snippet where it happens is :

```
Connection connection = null;
        CallableStatement callableStatement = null;

        try {
            connection = dataSource.getConnection();
            callableStatement = connection.prepareCall("{ call LOAD_DATA(?,TO_CLOB(?)) }");
            callableStatement.setString(1, fileName);
            callableStatement.setString(2, messageContent);
            callableStatement.execute();
            LOG.info("Data inserted successfully into REQUD table.");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            LOG.error(ex.getMessage());
            throw new DatabaseException(ex);
        } finally {
// to close connection/statements objects
            DbUtils.closeQuietly(callableStatement);
            DbUtils.closeQuietly(connection);

        }
```

There is no timeout issue, no thread interlocking and DB was entirely available without any downtime issues when this problem occured.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you see the transaction manager issuing a timeout warning means that this operation is part of larger transaction, typically either enclosed with UserTransaction.begin/commit or one that is managed by the container and thus boundaries don't appear explicitly in the application code.  The code snippet only shows the part of the transaction that relates to the database.  How are you determining that the data was successfully persisted to the table?  The appearance of the message `LOG.info("Data inserted successfully into REQUD table.");` does not guarantee that.  It only shows a certain amount of progress within the transaction, all of which could end up being committed or rolled back.  In the case of a transaction timeout, it ought to always be rolled back, and if it isn't being rolled back is a transaction manager bug.  If you confirm that the updates were truly persisted to the database, then you should open a case with IBM for the transaction manager issue.